# Show URL in JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I make service from json but i have problem to show url in json, this url  http://git.drieanto.net/LagiDimanaAPI/index.php/user/get_following/1 i try to show url from database but in json show `"avatar":"http:\/\/git.drieanto.net\/LagiDimanaAPI\/assets\/image\/avatar\/edwin.png"`.

how to make to show normal url like this `http://git.drieanto.net/LagiDimanaAPI/assets/image/avatar/edwin.png`

i used codeigniter this the code

```
function get_following($id_follower) {
        if ($this->muser->cek_following($id_follower) == TRUE) {
            $query = $this->muser->get_list_id($id_follower);

            $feedback["following"] = array();

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

                $query_list_user = $this->muser->get_all_name_user_from_id($row->id_user);

                if ($query_list_user->num_rows() > 0) {

                    $row_ = $query_list_user->row();

                    $query_status = $this->muser->get_status($row_->id_user);
                    $query_status->num_rows();
                    $row2 = $query_status->row();
                    $response['status'] = $row2->status;

                    $response['regid'] = $row_->regid;

                    $response['id_user'] = $row_->id_user;

                    $response['email'] = $row_->email;

                    $response['nama'] = $row_->nama;

                    $response['jenis_kelamin'] = $row_->jenis_kelamin;

                    $response['tanggal_lahir'] = $row_->tanggal_lahir;

                    $response['instansi'] = $row_->instansi;

                    $response['jabatan'] = $row_->jabatan;

$response['avatar'] = $row_->avatar;

                    $feedback['success'] = 1;
                } else {

                    $feedback['success'] = 0;
                }
                array_push($feedback["following"], $response);
            }
            $feedback['success'] = 1;
            echo json_encode($feedback);
        } else {
            $feedback['success'] = 0;
            echo json_encode($feedback);
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: This is an incomplete question. Where do you wanna show the URL? PHP? Objective-C? Javascript environment? Every language is different.

Comment: Without any code, it's impossible to help you. Something, somewhere, feels the need to put backslashes in front of the slashes in the string. That's perfectly fine, [`\/` is actually a valid JSON string escape (for `/`)](http://json.org/). So what you've quoted actually does have `http://git.drieanto.net/LagiDimanaAPI/assets/image/avatar/edwin.png` as the value of the `avatar` property.

Comment: i used codeigniter sorry i will show the code wait a minute

Comment: i have edit include code please help

Comment: @EdwinAndrianto: Did you see my comment above? Anything consuming that JSON will see the URL perfectly normally. To care about this, you'd have to actually look at the JSON itself.

Comment: @EdwinAndrianto: [Proof, if it were needed](http://jsbin.com/iqozix/1/) (source: http://jsbin.com/iqozix/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

It's just escaping the forwardslashes. You can use `str_replace($search_char, $replace_char, $string_to_search),` to remove them.

```
$stuff = json_decode($response);
$url = str_replace("\\", "", $stuff['url']);
```

It does sound like you're not decoding the JSON because I do believe PHP will unescape all of that stuff for you automatically.

Comment: If you know that particular string in the resulting decoded JSON object (now just a PHP array) is a URL, why would you have any problems removing the backslashes from it?

Comment: I'm not arguing he create invalid JSON. I'm arguing he needs to unescape the JSON string in his consuming application if his JSON decoder isn't doing it for him.

Comment: Dude. I never said it wasn't a valid JSON string. Are you forgetting he's 99% surely using JSON for transporting a message and in his consuming application (possibly a codeigniter php script) he will want to decode that JSON into a PHP array. and if that resulting array contains a STILL ESCAPED VALID JSON STRING he will want to unescape that string to print it to the screen.

Comment: @ Chris: I'm not saying you're saying his JSON is invalid (I did for about 15 seconds, because I misread you), and FWIW I completely agree that if he wants to remove the unnecessary escapes, a *targeted* `str_replace` would be the way to go. But not on the whole JSON string (original answer) and possibly not blindly even on just the URL. But its **completely optional**. There's nothing wrong with the string. It just contains the URL. Anything consuming the JSON will give you a normal URL, **exactly** as though the unnecessary escapes weren't there.

Comment: I didn't intend to str_replace the entire json string. Only the resulting decoded PHP string that for some reason still had escape characters in it. (Which it shouldnt.)

Comment: "Anything consuming the JSON will give you a normal URL, exactly as though the unnecessary escapes weren't there." I would assume this too, but that doesn't seem to be the OP's case.

Comment: @ Chris: The OP hasn't said anything is actually giving him trouble with this. As far as I can tell, he's just looked at the JSON and it looks funny to him. Best,